# Jenkins allow users to reset their passwords

Tags: jenkins, passwords, reset

I'm maintaining a Jenkins instance with over 200 users and regularly someone of the users ask me to reset his password. Is there a way to provide such a functionality, something like "forgot my password" link on the login page? I searched for plugins but also didn't find anything. I'm the only one who needs something like that???

Answer (score 2):

Use the AD authentication plugin or LDAP for authentication and authorization instead of Jenkins own database. This will save you(Jenkins Admin) the overhead of managing user account credentials. A user can reset account through AD or LDAP and it will be reflected in Jenkins as well.  In case you want to stick to Jenkins own database please use the rest interface  to design a custom password reset page for end users. This should work.